# exposed filter using two taxanomy term

Tags: views

i am having taxanomy names TEAM and create two fields home team and away team and want to create a exposed filter dropdown which is a combination of both teams please help me out

Comment: @mayur do u have drupal developing knowledge?

Comment: there is a team named taxanomy while creating content type i have added two fields named home team and away  team from team taxanomy but when i use views i have to crate a exposed drop down filter that filters both home and away team